# C++ Realtime Screen Capturing

Tags: c++, screenshot, real-time, screen-capture

I am trying to take screenshots of my desktop at 10fps while playing a game (GTA5) for use with another software. I tried the GDIscreencapture approach but while that is working I cant move my player in game. the screen freezes and takes screen shots, however I want to take screenshots while the player is moving. I don't require very high fps, 10-15fps is fine. I tried to find some other way but I still cant figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd try looking here: https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio.

Generally, I'd say OBS got it down how to properly capture the screen.

Comment: Is this in realtime? i dont want to record a video and then extract frames.

Comment: OK, i tried your approach but this is a gui tool i dont want that and plus it records the whole event i want to be able to integrate the screen capture in to a c++ code. Also i dont want recording only images at 10fps.

Comment: Alright so i tried the approach above with multi-threading and it worked like a charm. Thanks everyone.